# How to push file to browser after theme redirect

Tags: redirection, files

```
function epa_basket_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{    
    $basket = _epa_basket_get();   
    /* Direct download */
    if ($form_state['values']['radios'] == "0") {

        $wsdl =  _epa_config_get('wsdl_download_service_url');
        $options = array('features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE + SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
        $response = $client->GetURL(array_keys($basket['fids']));       

        //drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($response, TRUE) .'</pre>');      
        /*Direct download*/
        drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        drupal_add_http_header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        $filepath = sprintf('public://%s/%s.zip', _epa_config_get('zip_directory'), $response->URLDetails->linkURL);
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.'europarl_download_'.$response->URLDetails->linkURL .'.zip'.'"',
        );

        file_transfer($filepath, $headers);

        /*How can i execute this line of code*/
        $form_state['redirect'] = _epa_basket_get_url('confirmation');

 }
    /*Download by email */
    else {


        $basket_entry = (object) array(
            'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],
            'fids' => array_keys($basket['fids']),
        );

        if (!epa_basket_save($basket_entry)) {
            drupal_set_message(epa_helpers_t('An error occured, please try again.'), 'error');
        }

        $basket['processed'] = true;
        $_SESSION[_EPA_BASKET_SESSION_KEY] = $basket;
        $form_state['redirect'] = _epa_basket_get_url('confirmation');
    }
}
```

The above function is being executed after the submit button is called.
In the the first "Direct Download" a file is being pushed to the user's browser. 
How is it possible to redirect after that. A comment is in the code: /*How can i execute this line of code*/
What other alternatives do I have?